# how to use a bool variable in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am currently trying to use a boolean to check for when an event happens..
However I'm not sure how to use a boolean value in objective c

Heres what I'm doing.

//.h

```
BOOL *removeActivityIndicator;
//..
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *removeActivityIndicator;
```

//.m

```
if ([filteredArray count] == 0)
        {
            self.removeActivityIndicator = YES;
        }
        else if([filteredArray count] !=0)
        {
            tempArray = filteredArray;
        }
}
```

So I'm checking if the filtered array has no values if thats the case then I want to stop my UIActivityIndicator thats Is currently running in my uitableview cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//...

//Stop ActivityIndicator if arrays have no values for the user
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {        
        if ((indexPath.row == 1) && (self.removeActivityIndicator == 0)) //problem
        {
            //Stop activity indicators
            //[activityView stopAnimating];
            cell.accessoryView = nil;//replaces activity indicator
        }
    }

//...
```

My problem happens in the if parameters..

```
(self.removeActivityIndicator == 0)
```

I have no idea how to check if the BOOL is true or not.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to using self.removeActivityIndicator == NO;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in objective c true and false are YES and NO. Or, you can use this code:

```
if (!self.removeActivityIndicator) {};
```

it means

```
if (self.removeActivityIndicator == NO) {};
```

offcorse, `removeActivityIndicator` must be `BOOL` type

Comment: thanks.. This worked but its still not solving my issues.
For some reason when I allow this to happen it dose not show my activity indicator at all.. really starting to bug me.

Comment: activity indicator appiares in some time. if you removing it too fast, it will not appiar. if not, post some code where you adding it. better to make another queston for this: more chanses that other people will see it.

Comment: got it to work properly now :) just had to set it to YES when I call the protocol into the new main view that I'm working on. and it works mint! cheers for the help!

Answer (score 3):

there are a number of ways. just using the name with the NOT operator (!) in front works: `!self.removeActivityIndicator` or `self.removeActivityIndicator == NO` or `self.removeActivityIndicator == FALSE` will all work

Also as an aside: A BOOL type is a primitive, and therefore does not need to be declared as a pointer (using an *) as you have done. `BOOL remoteActivityIndicator;` is what you want as the declaration.